# Know who spawned a specific NSThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing an iOS application right now, and I have a quite high CPU usage. So I decided to profile it a bit.

With Xcode 5 things became easy, and I can see that "Thread #25" is using quite a lot of CPU. Sadly this thread is not named, and my app has external dependencies, so I don't have a means to add names for each thread.

**tl;dr: How can I know who spawned this "Thread #25" ?**

Comment: `NSThread` (and pretty much every threading mechanism I can think of) does not have the concept of a *parent thread*, like a process has a parent process.  So I don't believe you can.  You'll have to add a breakpoint in the method(s) the thread operates on and you might be able to determine it from there, however it's not obvious how that can be acheived.

Comment: You'd normally figure it out by looking at *what* the thread is doing. Which code is it running?

Comment: That's the point, the only two entries I have in the stack are pthread_create and pthread_kill...

Comment: Could it be that Xcode is hiding the rest of the stack trace? There's a slider to control the level of detail.

Comment: Indeed, I never paid too much attention to this slider, but it solved my problem. Many thanks !